# Delete selective data from InfluxDB based on timestamp

Tags: influxdb

Unfortunately I can't get any further with the following problem:
I have an InfluxDB with > 5,000,000 entries.
I would like to reduce its size.
To do this, all entries, except for the first one, should be deleted every quarter of an hour.
The timestamp has the following format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ms (ms = 3 digits)
Unfortunately, I cannot get the statement to execute the following:

Current entries (example):
2021-04-12 22:20:28.905
2021-04-12 22:20:58.908
2021-04-12 22:21:28.091
2021-04-12 22:21:58.912
2021-04-12 22:22:28.914
2021-04-12 22:22:58.916
2021-04-12 22:23:28.919
2021-04-12 22:23:58.921
2021-04-12 22:24:28.923
2021-04-12 22:24:37.582
2021-04-12 22:24:43.374

Reduce to:
2021-04-12 22:00:XX.XXX (Only the first value created at 10 pm, can also be several...)
2021-04-12 22:15:XX.XXX
2021-04-12 22:30:XX.XXX
etc.

I hope I have expressed myself clearly...

Many thanks in advance!
Ralf

No conclusion to solve this so far.